# How do I remove characters in my results with Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm new to Powershell, so I'm having a little trouble pulling the exact information that I need. I want to pull all the security groups for a given folder so that I can pipe that into a command that pulls the members of that group. To pull the groups, right now I have:

```
$Groups = @((Get-Acl $folder).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)
```

That pulls what I want, but it puts it in a *domain/group* format which I can't use. What can I do to get rid of everything up to and including the "\", so the group names can be piped into a new command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -replace switch to replace anything that matches a regular expression. So, to get rid of everything up to the first "\" in each group name, add this to the end of that line of code: `-replace "^.+\\"`

```
$Groups = @((Get-Acl $folder).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference) -replace "^.+\\"
```